# UBUNTU 12.04 - Wireless is not configured when I dont use wired connection

Tags: wireless

Wireless is not detecting in my ubuntu When I dont use wired connection.
During startup it shows below message :

"waiting for network configuration"

then:

"waiting an additional 60 seconds for network configuration"

And then system boot up without network configuration even Wireless does not work in this case.

Please find below my system detail:

[my system info](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6TKjECVZmj8V0ZnRFV3cGhUekE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually configure a wireless network. Go to System settings--> network--> Press + symbol to add new network select wireless tab and you can configure wireless connection by providing all details it ask you to give. If you didn't understand me, follow this link. This method needs to install wicd using which you can configure more easily "http://handytutorial.com/setting-up-wireless-network-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise/". All instructions are given.